# Adb Devices can't find my phone

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to get adb to see my Samsung Fascinate phone so that I can install my Android apps via usb to the phone. I am using osx 10.6.7.

When I run "adb devices" it does not list my device and "adb usb" says "device not found".

USB debugging is enabled and I have tried connecting in storage mode as well as media mode. When I am in storage mode I can see the phone's drive in Finder so I know that the usb connection works, however adb still can't find it.

I read that for Mac there are no usb drivers, that it's just supposed to work, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have the same issue, with a PIPO M1 tablet. I can browse the files on it as mass-storage. But adb simply will not find the device, despite enabling USB Debugging.

Comment: Bram, I have just added vendor id 0x2207 for my Pipo M3 into `~/.android/adb_usb.ini` and it works like a charm (after restarting service with `adb kill-server`)

Comment: Facing the same issues...In case someone lands here, try to watch the Devices tab from DDMS. I own two Macs (Snow Leopard MacMini 2.1 and Mountain Lion MacMini 6.1). In both, when connecting my AOC Breeze MW0812 (Android 2.3) with development-mode on, it blinks the name of the tablets for a second and then it disappears. Also, the newer Mac seem to blink a lot faster, but I was able to see it shows "offline". Also its worth noting that my Motorola Droid works perfectly with it.

Comment: Ejecting the SD card leads to it trying to display the running processes before vanishing. Maybe its to different issues: USB port (might need powered usb hub) and composite device incompability?

Comment: Got myself a powered usb hub and some new clues. Now I managed to get it to stay on ddms, but shows as offline. Sometimes it doesnt show up. from dmesg, when it's showing up, I get: USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): AOC Tablet MW0812 0xbb4 0xc02 0x222
USBF: 202.684 Endpoint 0x83 of the USB device "rk2918 sdk" at location 0x1d113500:  converting Bulk MPS from 64 to 512 (USB 2.0 Spec section 5.8.3)

Comment: MANAGED TO DO IT! Instead of chain connecting the hubs, I decided to connect everything just to the power hub. Its quite unstable, and tend to disconnect itself out, but it worked. Also, it made the hub unstable as well. I had to disconnect it. But its a start.

Comment: Hey, I had same issue and I solved it simply by using another USB-cable!! Didn't knew, that there are differences with the USB-cables (I have micro-USB)

Comment: My device appeared after enabling developer options on my phone.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I have a Samsung Galaxy and I had the same issue as you. Here's how to fix it:

In device manager on your Windows PC, even though it might say the USB drivers are installed correctly, there may exist corruption.

I went into device manager and uninstalled SAMSUNG Android USB Composite Device and made sure to check the box 'delete driver software'.   Now the device will have an exclamation mark etc. I right clicked and installed the driver again (refresh copy). This finally made adb acknowledge my phone as an emulator.

As others noted, for Nexus 4, you can also [try this fix](https://androidsecurity.wordpress.com/2013/06/05/install-google-nexus-4-adb-usb-drivers-on-windows-android-studio/).

Comment: Yeah I had tried that and didn't work for me, I'm glad it worked for you though so you didn't have to buy a whole new phone like me.

Comment: Have a Huaway 845 and suddently it stopped working in debug mode, I removed the driver like you said and now it shows up in `adb devices` again.

Comment: Worked for my Nexus 4.

Comment: For Nexus 4, follow these steps to install the drives: http://androidsecurity.wordpress.com/2013/06/05/install-google-nexus-4-adb-usb-drivers-on-windows-android-studio . This worked for me!

Comment: The Nexus 4 link (in the edited answer) also works for Nexus 7.

Comment: Did not work for Samsung Galaxy S3.

Answer (score 67):

Try doing this:

- Unplug the device
- Execute `adb kill-server && adb start-server`(that restarts adb)
- Re-plug the device

Also you can try to edit an adb config file `.android/adb_usb.ini` and add a line `04e8` after the header. Restart adb required for changes to take effect.

Comment: Restarting the server didn't help. Where exactly is this .android folder?

Comment: It's in your home folder. Should be something like `/Users/Justin/.android/`

Comment: At that point, I can only guess the problem :( It's all ok on my Mac(I don't have Fascinate, but a lot of other devices worked ok) **1.** Try to update Android SDK - maybe your adb is not the latest. **2.** Do you use custom or factory firmware on the device? Custom may cause problems with adb. **3.** If your phone is rooted, try to use [ADB over WIFI](https://market.android.com/details?id=bohlool.net.wifiadb)

Comment: Have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html also, and remember to kill and start server after making the change. Also, pull out your usb cable after restarting and put it back in. You should be fine.

Comment: I followed these steps AND rebooted the phone - which cleared the error

Comment: Activating USB debug mode has changed pretty recently: Note: On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by default. To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times.

Comment: make sure you have a matching version of android device

Comment: That solved my problem. Allow for debugging? RSA fingerprint bla bla was not showing. my device was Samsung Core 2. the question is why for another Samsung devices I didn't need to add the samsung vendor id? example: Samsung S3 NEO note: I am using mac.

Comment: Here "http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html" it says: If you're developing on Mac OS X, it just works. Skip this step. means no need to add vendors?! well, it looks like thats not really true! right?

Comment: @hasan83, it's true actually - there is no need to add vendors

Comment: My mac couldn't detect my Samsung S3 NEO until I added the samsung vendor. I can confirm that.

Comment: it seems situation has changed since [article](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) was published; or maybe the problem is in the specific device/osx version

Comment: i did'nt find adb_usb.ini file in .android folder

Comment: @mohsen, it seems that the configuration is more "automatic" these days, so there is no adb_usb.ini file anymore

Answer (score 24):

I did the following to get my Mac to see the devices again:

- Run `android update adb`
- Run `adb kill-server`
- Run `adb start-server`

At this point, calling `adb devices` started returning devices again. Now run or debug your project to test it on your device.

Comment: If you don't have the android and adb set as windows **environment variables**, just go to __C:\Program Files\Android\sdk\platform-tools__ (in explorer press Shift+RightClick in the white part and __open command window__) and use the following commands:
`..\tools\android.bat update adb`
`adb kill-server`
`adb start-server`

Comment: Great this worked for me on Ubuntu with a Nexus 7 tablet.

Answer (score 14):

I have a ZTE Crescent phone (Orange San Francisco II).

When I connect the phone to the USB a disk shows up in OS X named 'ZTE_USB_Driver'.

Running `adb devices` displays no connected devices. But after I eject the 'ZTE_USB_Driver' disk from OS X, and run `adb devices` again the phone shows up as connected.

Comment: Worked for my ZTE Blade.

Comment: Ejecting USB_DRIVER did the trick! Awesome judo solution :D :D :D

Comment: YES. I had the same problem with a ZTE Blade 3, which mounts a volume called "USB Driver". Ejecting it allowed ADB to detect the device.

Answer (score 11):

I just spent half a day trying to connect my various Android devices to my MacBook Pro (running 10.8.2).  It turns out to have been a Micro USB cable problem.  I have many Micro USB cables, but only the one that came packaged with my Galaxy Nexus works to connect the phones to my computer.  I don't know if this is due to damage, or some proprietary manufacturing, but please remember to try connecting the phone with the cable that was packaged with it.

Comment: I had the same issue. I didn't have to find the one packaged with the device just had to try a few others to find one that worked :-(

Answer (score 2):

I have a Fascinate as well, and had to change the phone's USB communication mode from MODEM to PDA.  Use:

- enter `**USBUI` (`**87284`)

to change both USB and UART to PDA mode.  I also had to disconnect and reconnect the USB cable.  Once Windows re-recognized the device again, "adb devices" started returning my device.

BTW if you use CDMA workshop or the equivalent, you will need to switch the setting back to MODEM.

Comment: Even though you are running OSX, I would expect this to still work.

Comment: I tried calling that phone # and it said "Welcome to Verizon Wireless. Your feature update could not be installed."