# Android: Alcatel phone not showing up in Eclipse/ADB

Tags: android

I bought a new Alcatel Onetouch 918n phone for app testing. I can't however get it to be recognized in eclipse to test.

After some painful steps, I now see "Alcatel Android ADB interface" in Device manager. But I just can't seem to make this phone visible to Eclipse/ddms/adb.

Since i somehow (I Think after installing Alcatel Android mgr on PC) got the OEM Usb driver installed, I think I don't need the google usb driver, correct?

And Yes usb debugging on phone is on.

Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://blog.fh-kaernten.at/wehr/?p=1182, where the author describes his problem with his device being in Device Manager but not showing up in ADB.  Also look at [Adb Devices can't find my phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469646/adb-devices-cant-find-my-phone).  Some other things to try:

- See what you get when you run ADB outside of Eclipse ("adb devices" from a command line). Sometimes Eclipse is finicky, so it may be better to troubleshoot this outside of it. Sometimes it's necessary to quit and restart Eclipse when it's not seeing your device, or unplug and re-plug your device.
- When you make any changes, use "adb kill-server" and "adb start-server" to stop and restart the adb server, before again trying to see your device.
- If possible, try a different device and see if it shows up in adb (though you'll probably have to install a driver for it first). That may tell you whether the problem is with your Alcatel phone or the software on your computer (missing SDK component, wrong USB driver, etc.)

Comment: Hi Brent
That first link was the resolution! I had to the device VID into the adb_usb.ini file manually. FANTASTIC! Thank you!