# adb "waiting for device" after installing usb drivers

Tags: android, adb

I am new to Android development and I am trying to get a test app onto my phone. My phone is an LG G3, and I am developing on Windows 8. Following the [official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html),I have installed the android sdk, and can run `ant debug`. However, when I run `adb install bin/MyFirstApp-debug.apk` it just says

```
error: device not found
error: device not found
error: device not found
- waiting for device -
```

I went to the [OEM USB Drivers](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) page, got the usb driver for my model, installed it through the installer provided by LG, and restarted my computer. Still getting the message.

When I try to update the drivers through the Windows 8 Device Manager, it says the drivers are up to date. I have also tried different combinations of turning both developer mode and usb debuggin on and off.

I have also tried setting up my Macbook as a development environment, but I still get the same error at this step, despite the documentation saying "If you're developing on Mac OS X, it just works. Skip this step." in reference to installing USB drivers.

Comment: Yup, question mentions I restarted my computer. Also just tried rebooting my phone. @admdrew

Comment: Ok. And `adb devices` doesn't return anything?

Comment: Nope. It just says `List of devices attached`, but the list is empty. Not sure if it matters, but the phone is in MTP mode and I can copy onto the MicroSD card or internal storage. However, I still get the same error when I turn off MTP mode. @admdrew

Comment: have you turned on "USB debugging" on your phone?

Comment: Yup. Have tried with USB debugging both on and off. @AlexP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in the second response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801676/lg-g3-not-recognized-by-eclipse). Needed to specifically set the USB connection to `Internet`

Comment: Please don't just link to answers, summarize them. If that link dies, this answer becomes useless.

Answer (score 1):

Does your device show up in Windows Explorer?  If not, this works in Windows 7. Try:

Start -> Computer (right click) -> Manage ->Device Manager -> Android Device -> Android Composite ADB Interface (Right click) -> Update Device Driver -> Browse My Computer for Driver Software -> Let me pick from list of device drivers on my computer

Comment: This is better suited as a comment to the question, especially given OP mentions he already checked out the driver in Device Manager.

Comment: @admdrew - I've been able to solve problems with the device drivers that are not fixed by using Device Manager.  When accessed this way (through Manage Computer), the device driver is fixed.

Comment: This answer seems to suggest the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469646/adb-devices-cant-find-my-phone?rq=1

Comment: The Device Manager is identical, regardless if viewed as a snap-in to Computer Management, or via its own dialog (they're literally pulling from the same location). That link does not make any mention of accessing Device Manager from different methods.